# Did Lucas originally say that Palpatine was evolving in Making of Return of the Jedi?

Tags: star-wars, the-empire-strikes-back

I heard that in The Making of Return of the Jedi, Lucas said that Palpatine's forehead was "split" because his body was evolving. Can anybody confirm this?

Comment: I'll need to find my copy... but there are references to that fact - e.g. [here](http://boards.theforce.net/threads/palpatines-body-evolving.50015465/)

Comment: Yeah I saw that thread. That's where my question came from. Thanks for checking.

Comment: And here I was thinking that his forehead was split because it had been struck by a lightning bolt, long before A New Hope.

Answer (score 2):

I've had a good look at the source mentioned in the thread (e.g. the Rinzler "[Making of Star Wars](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Making-Star-Wars-Definitive/dp/1781311900)" book) and I can find **no** mention of the Emperor being in the process of **evolution** or that his 'head split' is the early sign of his head actually opening fully, something which has the ring of fan-fiction.

[image: Palpatine]
[image: Palpatine 2]

The sole canon reference I can find to the Emperor 'evolving' is from the ROTJ "Making of Star Wars" Blu-Ray commentary. Shortly after Ian Mcdiarmid states that he was under the (apparently mistaken) impression that the Emperor [is over 100 years old](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086190/trivia) he very briefly mentions the "evolution" of the character.

It's certainly **not** intended to be a literal evolution, rather a discussion about how the character changed between Revill's portrayal in Empire Strikes Back and McDiarmid's portrayal in Return of the Jedi and beyond...

> According to Ian McDiarmid, George Lucas originally casted him simply
>   as the *physical* performance of the Emperor (similar to David Prowse as
>   Darth Vader). This became evident to him when a producer told him that
>   if he was able to get his voice close enough to Clive Revill's (who
>   portrayed the Emperor's voice in Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire
>   Strikes Back (1980)) Lucas would let him use his on-camera vocals in
>   the final cut of the film. However, McDiarmid felt he could conduct a
>   stronger, more wicked and demonic voice for the Emperor as opposed to
>   Revill's more aristocratic Emperor. Lucas, and even Steven Spielberg,
>   were so impressed with his take that it ended up becoming a signature
>   trait of the character.